# Cauchy problem doesn't have solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Prove that the following Cauchy problem doesn't have solution
>
> \begin{align} 
> y'(x) \sin(x) &= y \ln(y) \\  
> y \left( \frac{\pi}{2} \right) &=1 \\  
> \end{align}

I solved the ODE and I found:

$$\ln \left|\ln(y) \right|=\ln \left|\tan \left(\frac{x}{2} \right) \right|+c$$

When I put the initial condition, I found $\ln(0)$. How do I prove that this problem doesn't have a solution?

Comment: This is my problem, i try to found c and i stucked, because i found $ln(0)$ so doesn't exist c.

Comment: $ln(0)$ doesn't defined

Comment: This is no Cauchy or initial-value problem (IVP), as the coefficient of the (highest) derivative at the initial point is $\sin(\frac\pi2)=0$, the whole line $x=\frac\pi2$ does not belong to the domain of the DE, thus the initial point is not inside the domain.

Answer (score 2):

The ODE can be solved as:
$$
y(x)=e^{c_{1} \tan (x / 2)}
$$
According to The uniqueness of the solutions of differential equations and the solution satisfies Lipschitz condition. Bring in the initial value and you can get $c_{1}=0,y=1$.

Comment: I understand your answer, but according to the uniqueness of the solutions of ode, we see, that y(x)=1 is a solution for initial value problem.

Comment: Yes, so y=1 is the solution of the ODE.